# Tell when a CCAction is done running

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to be able to stop all actions when my animation sequence is done running, how would I do that? Right now i have:

```
CCAnimation *spinAnim = [CCAnimation
                                 animationWithSpriteFrames:spinAnimFrames delay:0.1125f];
        self.spinAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:spinAnim];
```

and then later:

```
[self.character runAction:self.spinAction];
```

So how would I be able to tell that the spin action is finished?

Comment: In cocos2d-iphone, You can use either CCCallFunc of CCCallBlock to get notify that CCAction is over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a sequence

```
CCCallFunc *callMe = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doneSpin)];
CCSequence *seq    = [CCSequence actions:spinAnim,callMe,nil];
self.spinAction    = seq;

[self.character runaction:self.spinAction];
```

and elsewhere in your code :

```
-(void) doneSpin {
    // spin action done, do whatever here !

}
```

Comment: For some reason this method was giving me an error saying spinAnim was an undeclared identifier.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh ok all I would need to do is make it global and that should work, I'll try that too

Comment: or put my lines to replace your definition for spinAction. A good way to handle these things is also to use blocks, i would encourage you to read-up on them.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do my research I appreciate everything!

Answer (score 0):

You can arrange a callback using CCCallFunc by adding it as the last action in a sequence of actions as follows :

```
[self.character runAction:[CCSequence actions:self.spinAction,[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(stopAllActions)],nil]];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to upvote :( I could only choose 1 answer and his was a bit more in depth.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized it with blocks like this:

(on .h)

```
typedef void(^actionTerminated)(void);
```

(on .m)

```
-(void) doJump:(float)delay
         times:(int)times
   actionBlock:(actionTerminated)actionBlock {
   // here there is your code, physicsBody adjusts..

   id block = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^
              { 
                // stop sound effect if there was
                actionBlock(); 
   }];
   actionSequence = [CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[self.action,block]];
   [self.sprite runAction:actionSequence];
}

// when you call do jump :
[self doJump:0.45 times:1 actionBlock^{
    // here jump action is terminated,do whatever you want..
}];
```